# How do i fetch all the Users "username" in database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a search page for my app that will allow users to search each other. The problem that I am having is i can only search the user that i am current logged into. (*note I made 8 other fake users*)

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

//let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

var ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")  

var filteredData = [UserModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    //filteredData = data

    ref.queryOrderedByValue().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let userSearch = userDict["username"] as? String

            self.filteredData.append(UserModel(NameDisplay: userSearch))
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].NameDisplay
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}
```

}

What I'm expecting is for every user to be displayed in the Tableview and then i can search. What is happening is only the user currently logged in is showing

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

Are your database rules set to allow any authenticated user to view usernames or is it set such that the currently auth'ed user is only allowed to view their username?

Your `ref` is drilling all the way down to the currently authenticated user. So your snapshot would only get the username of the current user because your ref is too deep. This is probably the issue, but your database rules may still need to be adjusted once you make this change.

Comment: My rules are "{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}"

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
```

is getting a specific child from the users collection, if you only get the users object then you will have access to the entire collection of child objects to which you can search for other users.

Comment: How can i recode this to get only the users object?

Comment: Remove .child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")

Comment: When i removed it now nothing returns back from the database, my rules are "{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true } }", do you think this may be the reason?

Comment: Those rules allow anyone to read/write. It is not because of your rules.

Comment: Okay i think i got it figured out. Thank you for the help

Comment: Yeah, what i did, I just removed .child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)") from the write reference and the read reference, and for write replaced it with .childByAutoId()